# How to run .csproj files downloaded from a website? Shows error "the system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZKpC.png)I downloaded an ASP.NET project from a website. The project is an online banking project and contains multiple web forms and a database features. When I open the .csproj file it throws me an error saying "the system cannot find the file specified". how can I open and run the file?

Comment: May be project is created in older version of visual studio

Comment: So how do I run it then?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: visual studio 2017.

Comment: Just a workaround: create a new project and append all files and folders of the sample project.

Comment: Post full error message or its screenshot.